# Cannot make loops in a 2-list matching program compare and print needed elements

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop

I have trouble making loops in a 2-list matching program that compares and prints out the needed element indices when they occur in both lists.

```
word = "Hello"

consonants = ['b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'z']

for character in range(len(word)): 
    for char in range(len(consonants)): 
        if consonants[char] == word[character]: 
            consonant = word[character]
            print consonant
```

The program identifies if the consonant is present in the string by looping though the `word` and then though the `consonants` list containing all possible consonants, testing if the current element of the `word` matches one of the elements of the `consonants` list.

The output should be the index of each element that is a consonant, but instead I get this:

```
1
1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use list comprehension

```
>>>> [ind for ind, letter in enumerate(word) if letter.lower() in consonants]
[0, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Clear and elegant list comprehension: +1

Answer (score 1):

> The output should be the index of each element that is a consonant

Which index?  If you mean the *index into consonants*, then:

```
>>> [consonants.index(c) for c in word.lower() if c in consonants]
[5, 8, 8]
```

If efficiency were important, use two steps:

```
>>> d = dict((char, i) for (i, char) in enumerate(consonants))
>>> [d[c] for c in word.lower() if c in consonants]
[5, 8, 8]
```

Comment: `list.index()` will cost an extra `0(n)` at each iteration resulting in the entire loop to take `0(n^2)`

Answer (score 1):

How about this piece of code

```
word = "Hello"

consonants = ['b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p',
            'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'z']

for char in word.lower():
    if char in consonants:
        print consonants.index(char),
```

Output : 5 8 8

I have used lower on word because capital 'H' is not found in consonant list.